# TabularDataset "topandasdataframe()" - does not support pandas errorbadlines?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to skip lines that produces more columns than intended while loading to a pandas dataframe.

Like this Pandas Option: When error_bad_lines = False, pandas will skip these lines.

How to achieve this with to-pandas-dataframe()?

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py#to-pandas-dataframe-on-error--null---out-of-range-datetime--null--

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py#to-pandas-dataframe-on-error--null---out-of-range-datetime--null--) this option is not available with to_pandas_dataframe(), you can only use on_error='null' to replace the failed values with null or fail with exception if 'fail' is used.